# Remove a line from a CSV powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-cmdlet

I currently have the following csv

```
These, Are, Several, Columns
-----, ---, -------, -------
"And", "here", "is", "data"
"And", "some", "more", "data"
```

While I wish I could simply change the process that creates the csv to remove the line of dashes that isn't possible.

The line of dashes is always the 2nd line, can I use powershell to remove the 2nd line of data?

Bonus question, I'm looking to add at the bottom a blank line, followed by a paragraph of text. I'm guessing I would be able to use the add-content cmdlet, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command should work:

```
gc file.txt | ? { $_ -notlike '*----*' } | sc file2.txt
```

It essentially performs the following tasks:

1. Retrieves the content of `file.txt`
2. Filters (using `Where-Object`) content for lines not like ----
3. Writes the remaining content to `file2.txt`

Comment: thanks for the edit. I was just about to go look up what each section did. Any chance you could help with that adding a paragraph into the csv?

Comment: Yeah, just like you said: Add-Content -Path File2.txt "BACKTICKnParagraph of text with a new lineBACKTICKngoes here just like this." Replace "BACKTICK" with an actual backtick. The BACKTICKn represents a new line.

Comment: am I able to save back into file.txt?

Comment: Remove-Item File.txt;
Move-Item File2.txt File.txt;